# Can you teach me what the difference between ‘round’ and ‘around’?

Tags: word-usage

I see ‘round’ and ‘around’ are uses in the book. Most ones can be placed by the other ones, I think. Can you teach me what the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

**Around** is an adverb or preposition that can sometimes be replaced by **round** used as an adverb or preposition.

He walked **around/round** the block.

But round can also be an adjective or verb, and cannot be replaced with 'around' when used in those functions.

He **rounded** the bend. (round as verb)

The plate was **round**.  (round as adjective)

Comment: I'd like to add that round, without a contracting apostrophe prefixed to it, is not an adverb or preposition. So, around can be replaced by 'round, but it needs the apostrophe. This arose from the a being dropped in spoken conversation for convenience. **edit** Oof, tricked by American/British English differences. It would appear "round" is indeed an adverb in British vernacular. https://www.dictionary.com/browse/round

Comment: Yes, that's how it arose, but you'll now see it without the apostrophe quite frequently, especially in phrases like "round-the-clock care/coverage." It is itself listed as an adverb or preposition, without the apostrophe, in several dictionaries, with reference to 'around' for meaning.

Answer (score 0):

When "around" is used to mean "in the area of" it is less likely to be replaced by "round", although it still can be:

> I often saw him around the neighborhood.

When "around is used to mean "approximately" the use of "round" is also less likely:

> I think he weighs around 200 pounds.
>
> It should take me around 3 days to finish

In this usage "about" can be used in place of "around".